# data of string to map in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to convert string in to map in java script.

```
123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com
```

Expected output:

```
[123,ABC S,ABC.s@xyz.com],[234,Def K,def.k@xyz.com]
```

I have tried this:

```
var input ="123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com";

var res1 = input.split('|');

var res2 = res1.toString().split('!');

//123,ABC S,ABC.s@xyz.com,,234,Def K,def.k@xyz.com
document.write(res2);

var map = {123:'ABC S':'ABC.s@xyz.com'};

console.log(map);
```

Comment: Is it just this one string, or do you have lots of these you want to format? Are they all the same structure?

Comment: Could you edit the input again?

Comment: input is String that i have to convert in to map .

Comment: I'm confused. Your expected output suggests two arrays, but in your example code you're trying to get the input into a JS object (or map). They're two different structures. Do you want arrays, or this: `{123:'ABC S':'ABC.s@xyz.com'}` (which isn't a valid object, but still...)?

Answer (score 1):

> Expected output:
>
> [123,ABC S,ABC.s@xyz.com],[234,Def K,def.k@xyz.com]

Simply

```js
var input = "123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com";
var output = input.split("!!").map(function(item) {
  return item.split("|");
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( output, 0, 4 ) )
```

Split the `input` string by `!!` and then `split` the individual `item`s from this first `split` by `|`

Comment: Thanks, I am new to javascript can you explain (function(item)), 'item is a method.

Comment: @geeta `item` is the argument to the function.

Comment: map(function(item)(string already converted in to map) then why we are using JSON. Thanks

Comment: Map doesn't convert an array to map, it is a method of Array to iterate the items of the array and returns a value against each item of the original array .

Comment: @geeta jus check the updated answer below where you can get key value pairs of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input ="123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com";
var output = input.split( "!!" ).map(item=>item.split( "|" ));
```

use arrow functions

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Hi I suggest expanding on your answer to explain to the asker what the code does and why this answer works so they can understand better for the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input ="123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com";    
var res1 = input.split('!!').toString().split('|');   
document.write(res1 );    
var map = {res1 [0]:res1 [1]:res1 [2]};
```

Comment: ToString is unnesesary ins some cases you will have refereance error

Answer (score 0):

what's your meaning about these code?

```
var map = {123:'ABC S':'ABC.s@xyz.com'};   
console.log(map);
```

**follow yours questions**

Hi I am trying to convert string in to map in java script.

```
123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com
```

Expected output:

```
[123,ABC S,ABC.s@xyz.com],[234,Def K,def.k@xyz.com]
```

**Heres My answer**

```
var in1 = "123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com";
var out = in1.split("!!").map(function(v,i,self){
 return v.split("|")
})
```

Comment: after splitting of string i am trying to convert in to map 'var map = {123:'ABC S':'ABC.s@xyz.com'};  that's why written.

Comment: it is syntax error! if you want to JSON, only {key: value, key:value} allowed

Comment: also {key:array,key:array} is allowed

Comment: can you write 
    var map = {123:'ABC S':'ABC.s@xyz.com'};   
    console.log(map); expected string

Comment: Expectedoutput :- [123,ABC S,ABC.s@xyz.com],[234,Def K,def.k@xyz.com]    

var res1 = input.split('|');

var res2 = res1.toString().split('!!');
var output = res2.map(function(item)
{
 return item;

});

console.log(output);
document.write(output); Can you check above my code its correct or not.

Comment: this just array, not map and without any relationship with your code var map = {123:'ABC S':'ABC.s@xyz.com'};   
console.log(map);

Comment: Please check initial i have mentioned input string "123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com" and expected output:[123,ABC S,ABC.s@xyz.com],[234,Def K,def.k@xyz.com]

Comment: Please check my code i have user map(function(item)) is it correct?

Comment: ...,no value questions! and didn't read any document or google's questions!syntax err without ensure!I just want to know who votes the questions

Comment: This question has no value

Comment: after modification of code asked for review . Leave it.

Answer (score -1):

You can get it done by below code

```
var input ="123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com";

var res1 = input.split('|').toString().split('!!');

function getMappedData(item) {
    var temp=item.split(",");
    var newArr={};
    for(var i=0,len=temp.length;i<len;i+=2) {
        newArr[temp[i]]=(temp[i+1]);
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(res1.map(getMappedData));
//result [{"123":"ABC S"},{"234":"Def K"}]
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Suvethan/anLeyzmz/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
var a = '123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com!!234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com'
var b = a.split('!!') //["123|ABC S|ABC.s@xyz.com", "234|Def K|def.k@xyz.com"]
var c1 = b[0].split('|'); //["123", "ABC S", "ABC.s@xyz.com"]
var c2 = b[1].split('|'); //["234", "Def K", "def.k@xyz.com"]
```